# FME autocad to csv

Tags: fme-form

I have a few building blocks and land parcels in a dxf file that look like this

[image]

I am writing to a csv file using FME the following attributes:

**land parcel number | xmin|  xmax  |  ymin | ymax**

The last four attributes correspond to the bounding box of each land parcel.

I want to add the attribute 'building block' to each land parcel. I.e. in the above example Γ251 (=autocad_string) should correspond to each land parcel shown.

**land parcel number | xmin|  xmax  |  ymin | ymax | building block name**

Any ideas on how make this work?

Comment: You are doing 2 things right? one is the csv, the other is adding the additional label into the autocad?

Comment: Why are you using PointOnAreaOverlayer? Are the parcels and the blocks not both areas?

Comment: U2ros: it is producing a csv with the above mentioned attributes (land parcel number | xmin| xmax | ymin | ymax | building block name)

Comment: sgrieve: In this dxf  land parcels and building blocks are designed using autocad_lines, I then build areas in FME to retrieve the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so for the xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax you will need boundsextractor (collects actual mmin/max of the feature) or boundingboxreplacer/extractor combined with bounds extractor.

From the picture i take it that buildings also have a polygon (+ text labels). So first thing i would do is join those labels with building polygons (pointonareaoverlay), then simply overlay buildings (with attribute building name) with parcels.

If you can post a sample dwg, i could make you a fme workspace

[image]

Comment: Sample dwg: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C9AA3D4A3BF6936E!386&authkey=!AH0RCLHf3ctPVgE

Comment: Okay, i downloaded the sample file. Do i understand correctly: Yellow line represent parcels and small yellow labels represent parcel numbers (Layers: NidAir, NidOria), and big yellow label is a building block names and the green polygons represent building blocks? (One green polygon has no corresponding big label, just so you know)

Comment: Exactly. Yellow line represent parcels and small yellow labels represent parcel numbers (Layers: NidAir, NidOria), and big yellow label is a building block names and the green polygons represent building blocks.

Comment: Okay, check out this first workspace to get you started: http://ge.tt/9MbItBP/v/0 Please note, that i used topolgybuilder-areabuilder because your dwg files contains lines. Unfortunetely this produces a few parcels that dont actually exist, so the final csv file needs to be cleaned up a bit, or, you need to have a dwg with closed polylines (best). Anyway, this should get you started into the right direction. Also, i produced i few shape files, so you can check intermediate results

Comment: I am using an FME build of 2010 (I cant use a topologybuilder). I am using the textproperty extractor for parcel strings and I add pointonAREAoverlay. For building blocks I am using again the TextProperty Extractor

Comment: I ll post a screenshot when i get home :)

Comment: Note, that you should really prepare the dwg in a way to avoid the use of topologyBuilder and AreaBuilder, ie. have closed polylines to start with!